# Performance difference between list of byte array and hashmap having byte array as value

Tags: java

I want Suggestion that which one is better based on performance?

List<byte[]>

or

HashMap<String,byte[]>

For me key doesnt matter. I'm going to store only list size of 2 in object. First one represent one constant and another represent another constant.

Also is there any better way of solution other than two  also please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *"Also is there any better way of solution other than two also please suggest me."* - You haven't properly explained the problem yet ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a pojo class to hold the values ?

```
Class ConstantHolder {

  private final byte[] constant1;
  private final byte[] constant2;

  public Holder(byte[] constant1, byte[] constant2) {
    this.constant1 = constant1;
    this.constant2 = constant2;
  }

  getters for constants;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

How can you compare a List to a Map? They're completely different things.  Also, it depends on which operations you perform.

Lastly, you're comparing a concrete implementation (hashmap) to an abstract interface (list).  That makes no sense.

If you don't need a key, you don't need a map.  As for performance of different list implementations, they're documented in the javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you don't have key-value relationship, don't use map.
2. Don't mix generics with arrays (e.g. `List<byte[]>`).

If the two are not related, use two separate `byte[]` variables, if they are, use `byte[][]` (assuming you can't do `List<List<Byte>>`).

Comment: Not able to understand Don't mix generics with arrays. please explain briefly

Answer (score 0):

List:
List works faster vertically in the following cases:

1. adding a new object at the beggining and at the end
2. deleting at the beginning and at the end
   List works slower vertically in the following cases:
3. Searching is some sort of slow when it must serch vertically because
   the objects are linked linked-list wise.
4. adding and deleing at the middle.

HashMap:
Is a map and may search vertically and horizontally by the key:

1. Iterators are used to search and are slow in adding(to check unique
   key if applies here)
2. deleting is fast
3. search is fast